# How to make scroll in a JavaFX Tableview disappear

Tags: css, javafx

[image]

There're two tables in this picture, the left table has a vertical scroll while the right one hasn't, so disgusting, so I wonder how to remove the scroll in the left tableview.

This is my code of left table in FXML:

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing the code I can't give the exact code, but if it's a table the following would work.

In the css put:

```
table { 
   overflow : hidden;
}
```

This disables scrolling and hides all content that falls outside of the visible part of your table.

Comment: It's JavaFX, not HTML, so this CSS won't do anything.

Comment: It seems not working. I use it in CSS for FXML, should I change anything?

Comment: You can try changing the selector to `.table-view .scroll-bar` and the style to `visibility: hidden;`.